# HTML variable causing error in CGI file

Tags: javascript, html, variables, cgi

I am having problem printing a particular variable from my cgi file. I receive this variable, called totalCost from my webpage and then try to print it, but nothing happens. All the other variables can be received successfully from the webpage and printed out on another webpage via my cgi file, except for this one..i've checked for case sensitivity but that didnt help

The code in html...

```
<tr>  <td colspan=3 padding=2><b> Total =  $ </b> <input type= "text" id="totalCost" disabled= true name= "totalCost" size ="5" maxlength="5" value= 0.00 /> <td> <tr>
```

the computeCost function

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

function computeCost(){

var apples= document.getElementById("appleQty").value;
var oranges=document.getElementById("orangeQty").value;
var bananas=document.getElementById("bananaQty").value;

var totCostTemp=0.69*apples + 0.59*oranges + 0.39*bananas;

document.getElementById("totalCost").value= totCostTemp; 

}
</script>
```

In cgi file, which I write using Perl, I receive my variable in this manner:

```
my ($appleQty, $orangeQty, $bananaQty, $user, $cardType, $c) = (param("appleQty"), param("orangeQty"), param("bananaQty"), param("user"), param("cardType"), param("totalCost"));
```

then try to print out in this manner..

```
print header;
print start_html("Receipt"),
print h3("Fruit Store: Order Summary"),
table({-border => 2} ,caption("Your Receipt"), 
Tr([th("Name:").td($user),th("Payment Method:").td($cardType),th("Fruit Type").td("Quantity"), th("Apple").td($appleQty), th("Oranges").td($orangeQty), th("Bananas").td($bananaQty), th("Total Cost:").td($c)]));
print end_html;
```

Please note...all variables except totalCost get printed correctly. totalCost is not printed at all in my resultant webpage...I think this has to do with the fact that I did some computation and perhaps did not store it properly in the id. But I dont know how to resolve that..

thank you for advising!

Comment: Your problem is not related to Perl, but HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled fields don't get posted. So you simply need to modify the field to make it readonly. Like :

```
<input type="text" id="totalCost" readonly="true" name="totalCost" size ="5" value="0.00" />
```

If you don't like the color of the readonly field, you can use a CSS to modify it like :

```
<style>
    input[readonly=true] {
     color:silver;
    }
</style>
```

---

Or for better CSS compatibility :

```
<style>
    .disabled {
      color:silver;
    }
</style>

<input type="text" id="totalCost" readonly="true" name="totalCost" size ="5" value="0.00" class="disabled" />
```

You may also use hidden fields, but you don't have to change your current code.

Answer (score 2):

If the `<input>` element is never enabled, then it will not be sent to the server when the form is posted.

If you don't want the user to be able to update the field, then don't use an ordinary "text" `<input>`.  Put a `<span>` there to hold the value, and update an enabled "hidden" `<input>` instead.

```
function computeCost(){

  var apples= document.getElementById("appleQty").value;
  var oranges=document.getElementById("orangeQty").value;
  var bananas=document.getElementById("bananaQty").value;

  var totCostTemp=0.69*apples + 0.59*oranges + 0.39*bananas;

  document.getElementById("totalCost").value= totCostTemp;
  document.getElementById('totalCostView').innerHTML = '$' + totCostTemp;

}
```

and the page would look like:

```
<td>
  <span id='totalCostView'>$0.00</span>
  <input type='hidden' id='totalCost' name='totalCost' value='0.00'>
</td>
```

Comment: thanks pointy, i dont quite understand how to use the span tag though, it's meant for formatting text right? how'd you use this to prevent the user from inputting data in the text box?

Comment: You'd use a simple `<span>` like that so that you can find it via Javascript. It doesn't *have* to be a `<span>`, but that's the simplest thing to use. This way the user will see the total cost on the screen, but it won't be in an editable text field. The form field is of type "hidden", so it will not be visible but the value will be posted back when the form submits.

Comment: i'm sorry, i cant visualise how to write it...could you give an example in javascript?

Comment: The code is *right there in the answer you're commenting on* !!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you're going to discover really soon now that doing monetary calculations with Javascript floating-point values does not work very well.

Comment: haha okay thanks...so u're saying the form field is hidden but not disabled...but i want the user to see the total cost, this is where I need to use span, but how?

Comment: yea discovered that :) my the totalCost variable in my cgi file is okay now, but it outputs lots of dec places.

Comment: The `<span>` is, as you say, just an element where content should go. You see in that code where it finds the `<span>` by its "id" value ("totalCostView")?  Well, by updating the "innerHTML" property, the new computed total will show on the screen.  The "hidden" input field will post the value back to the server because it is never disabled.

Comment: it seems so obvious, but I cant do it! can you advise on what I should write?

Comment: <tr>  <td colspan=3 padding=2><b> Total =  $ </b> <input type= "text" id="totalCost" name= "totalCost" size ="5" maxlength="5" value= 0.00 READONLY /> <td> <tr>